# Visual Studio forgets earlier defined functions Python

Tags: python, visual-studio

I am very new to Visual Studio and I ran into a problem. I am trying to run the following code in Python in Visual Studio:

```
#importing packages
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup

#my_url = "https://m.mcdonalds.be/nl/restaurant"
my_url = "https://www.newegg.com/global/be-en/p/pl?d=graphics+cards"

#opening connection, grabbing the page
uClient = uReq(my_url)
page_html = uClient.read()
uClient.close()
```

If I run the entire piece of code I get no errors. But if I run line by line I get errors like:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:\HLIS-Administration\..\tempCodeRunnerFile.py", line 1, in <module>
    page_html = uClient.read()
NameError: name 'uClient' is not defined
```

Since the entire script is a lot longer I don't want to run the entire script each time I added a new line. How to get over this? And is there an easy way (shortcut) to run 1 line and move automatically to the next with my cursor? Thank you.

Comment: Why would visual studio "remember" what you did in previous executions? The closest thing you can do is to use the debugger, it allow you to check the value of each line, but you still have to run all the relevant parts.

Comment: I am used to R Studio and there when I declare a variable it stores it and I could call it again. But is it then true that in Visual Studio you run the entire program again each time?

Comment: Never worked with R Studio, but I imagine it's for R language? Python is a different animal. By the way why are you using visual studio in the first place? why not an IDE for Python?

Comment: I thought Visual Studio is an IDE which can be used for Python? Or am I wrong? Is it better to use for example Jupyter Notebooks?

Comment: It can be used, but there are dedicated IDEs for Python like Jupyter Notebooks you mentioned or Pycharm, which is very similar to Visual Studio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although the question is somewhat vague (there is no "running line by line" in Python) I think you may want to debug the code. This way you should be able to step through your code and skip pieces or hook into certain parts.

How to setup python debugging in Visual Studio is described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/python/debugging-python-in-visual-studio?view=vs-2019)